# Description of numeric type in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking to describe how numbers are stored in javascript to a lay person. Would the following statement be accurate:

```
Very large numbers in javascript are often approximated.
However,precision should be guaranteed to 16 digits.
For example, 123455.373849 can always be represented accurately,
but the number 9,007,199,254,740,991,293 may not be.
```

Is there a better way to explain it, or any inaccuracies in the above statement?

Comment: For example, `0.1` is not represented exactly.

Comment: @OrangeDog but you can do a `toString` and show it as 0.1, right?

Comment: Try doing `0.1 + 0.2`.

Comment: `0.1 + 0.2 === 0.3` ...

Comment: @JonasWilms nope, it's `0.30000000000000004`

Comment: `(0.1+0.2).toFixed(1) "0.3"` ?

Comment: @David542 well obviously, you can represent any number you want with a string.

Comment: @OrangeDog I guess my question then is more along the lines of "What is the maximum number of digits in a number that we can use where `toFixed` will be exact? For example `0.045.toFixed(3)` will be exact, but `0.293787234867238746283467823764234234.toFixed(36)` will not.

Comment: @David542 `(1/3).toFixed(1)` will not be exact, so none.

Comment: @OrangeDog I mean "accurate to that number of decimal places".

Comment: @David542 `2e306.toFixed(1)` is also wrong.

Comment: @OrangeDog -- right, so is there a max number of digits in a number that javascript will accurately be able to represent it as a number or decimal? Obviously that number is under 300...

Comment: @David542 Jonas already answered that question: "Up to 53bit integers can be represented accurately and every number that can be represented as `(53bit) * 2 ** (10bit)`". That does not equate to a number of decimal digits.

Comment: @David542 Note that Python floating point numbers work exactly the same way that JavaScript floating point numbers work.

Comment: @Pointy Python has both (unlimited size) ints and floats. JavaScript only has Numbers.

Comment: @OrangeDog yes it does, and the floating point values are IEEE 754 values; that's why my comment specifically said "Python floating point numbers".

Comment: @Pointy you're likely to cause even more confusion

Comment: @OrangeDog the OP has lots of Python rep points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16 digits? No, not really. Up to 53bit integers can be represented accurately and every number that can be represented as `(53bit) * 2 ** (10bit)`.

Also, there are no 64bit integers in JavaScript, there are 64bit floating point numbers (and only 53bit of that hold the integer part), and BigInts that can have far more bits.

> Very large numbers in javascript are often approximated.

Kind of, very large integers can only be approximated (or you use BigInts), however even small non integers, e.g. 0.1 can also not be represented exactly.

> For example, 123455.373849 can always be represented accurately

No, probably not.

> but the number 9,007,199,254,740,991,293 may not be.

Yup, thats far beyond 2 ** 53 - 1.

Comment: I see. So if you used `toString` to format the data, is there a number of digits that you can guarantee under which it would always be exact?

Comment: `toString` will do some rounding if used with non integers.

Comment: sorry I mixed up the two, I meant using `toFixed`.

Comment: `toFixed` will round too. You cannot guarantee any number of digits. Take `1/3` for example ... How many digits do you expect?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `BigInt` will let you have as many digits as will fit in memory.

Comment: @JonasWilms well `1/3` evaluates correctly to 16 digits in javascript when I try it -- `(1/3).toFixed(100)
"0.33333333333333331482` ==> `"0.3333333333333333148296162562473909929394721984863281250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"`

Comment: Again: Floating point numbers are not meant to provide accurate calculations.

Comment: @JonasWilms right, understood. So then is there a number of digits where we know the integer/decimal representation will be "correct"?

Comment: NO.  Numbers are **binary floating point**.  2 and 10 do not have the same prime factorization. All languages based on binary floating point (IEEE 754) numbers behave the same way. There are no "guarantees".

Comment: No. `1000000000000.1`.

Comment: @JonasWilms `1000000000000.1.toFixed(1)
"1000000000000.1"` that seems to be displayable to one decimal place? Though if we add another digit it would be wrong: `10000000000000000000.10.toFixed(1)
"10000000000000000000.0"`

Comment: @David542 understand that `1/10` is a *repeating fraction* in binary representation. It cannot be represented exactly. It's like `1/3` expressed as a decimal fraction.

Comment: `Math.log(2 ** 53) / Math.log(10)` gives ~15.94, so you can't even represent Integers with 16 digits accurately (only 15), and that doesn't even account for the exponentation.